# Bevel not...beveling properly

Tags: modeling, bevel, effects

I'm taking a course and the instructor has beveled an edge and I cannot get the same result. My bevel only bevels on segment on one side then the rest, about 4 or 5 segments bevel on the other side. Other words the bevel is not beveling evenly on the top of a cylinder. Pictures below

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe you've scaled your object in Object mode and haven't applied the scale? Try this: Cancel your bevel, select your object in Object mode, ctrl A > Apply Scale, then, back to Edit mode and try to bevel again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bevel appears distorted because the mesh has non-uniform scaling.

You probably scaled the object along a specific axis e.g. <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd>. If you instruction had done this in edit mode, the scale doesn't change, but if one scales it in object mode, the scale will remain unapplied non-destructively. The visual appearance is the same. You can apply the scale in object mode, then return to edit mode and bevel.

1. Leave edit mode and go into object mode <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>.
2. Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and choose *Scale*.
3. Go back into edit mode <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>, the bevel will work as expected.

Comment: Read: [Why is it important to apply transformations to objects data](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data/7967#7967)