# Why does not bevel work right with circled shape?

Tags: modeling, bevel

my shape:
[image]
**my problem (I selected circle and press CTRL+B, then I draged bevel):**
[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Try to apply the scale and make sure the normals are pointing in the right direction, the issue in most cases.

Comment: FILE - https://pasteall.org/blend/87ed5e8a08584b61adfb8e2e7af78808

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bevel not...beveling properly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112057/bevel-not-beveling-properly)

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on @Ribbit12 's point, one way to get a clean bevel here is to bevel to an ngon, or an inset.. you can always delete the ngon and *(Face Menu) > Grid Fill* later, if you need topology in the flat face.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To be honest your geometry is quite bad that`s also one problem.
But the other one is that you have bevelled across an edge loop and the mesh goes crazy. If you bevel across an edge loop that's what happens.

Try applying the scale too by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.